# Proof of the fact that for an analytic surface restricted in neigbourhood of the origin we can transform away high order terms

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I'm sorry for the lame title. I was not sure how to write it properly. I have heard a lot the following:

Let $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 + O_3(x,y)$ be analytic around the origin. Then there exists a neighbourhood of the origin and an analytic change of coordinates such that $f$ is transformed to $x^2+y^2$ in this neighbourhood.

This is something that every algebraic geometer seems to know but no one could give me a reference for the proof. Where can I find the proof?

Note that the $f$ chosen was an example and not the actual function I am interested in.

I am actually interested to see what happens when $f$ is formal. In particular can I construct a formal transformation that does the same? Will this transformation have the same Gevrey character as $f$?

Comment: I think this may be the Morse Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma

Comment: I have difficulties translating this in a language I am comfortable with. What happens if the lowest order terms of $f$ are of order 3 or more? Does the lemma assume order 2 at most?

Comment: Let $f=f_d+f_{d+1}+\cdots$, where $f_k$s are homogeneous in 2 varibales of degree $k$. Further assume that $f_d$ is the product of distinct linear polynomials. Then, after a change of variables (in power series), one can make $f$ to be just $f_d$. I think you can find a proof in Zariski's book on surfaces. I also think (memory is hazy) the proof uses Weierstrass Preparation and Hensel's lemma.

Answer (score 0):

I state the basic theorem about formal power series in two variables over the complex numbers. If $f(x,y)=f_d+f_{d+1}+\cdots$, where $f_k$ are homogeneous polynomials in $x,y$ of degree $k$ and $x$ divides $f_d$, but $x^2$ does not divide $f_d$, then there exists a formal change of variables so that $f=xg$. If $d=2$, in your case $x^2+y^2$ is the same as $xy$ after a linear change, you can easily see from the above result that $f$ can be assumed to $xy$.

A few words about the proof of the result. Write $f_d=xP$. Then, the hypothesis says $P$ is monic (upto a constant) in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of degree $d-1$. Now, like in many such proofs, one recursively solves for $A_2,A_3,\ldots, B_d, B_{d+1},\ldots$, homogeneous polynomials with subscripts denoting the degree, so that $(x+A_2+\cdots+A_r)(P+B_d+\cdots+B_{r-2+d})\equiv f\bmod (x,y)^{r+d}$. For this, one basically divides the term of interest by $P$ and get a remainder which is naturally a multiple of $x$ by degree considerations.